# how to print php data into html tag

Tags: php, html

```
 <?php

 include 'connection.php';

 if(isset($_POST['val'])){
 $a = $_POST['val'];

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM car_details where id= '".$a."'";
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $con );
  if(! $retval ) {
   die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
  }

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

     $ID = $row['ID'];
     $Name = $row['Car_Name'];
     $Category = $row['Category'];
     $Transmision = $row['Transmision'];
     $Seats = $row['seats'];
     $EnginePower = $row['EnginePower'];
     $EngineCapacity = $row['EngineCapacity'];
     $MaxSpeed = $row['MaxSpeed'];
     $TankCapacity = $row['TankCapacity'];
     $Car_Details = $row['Car_Details'];
     $img = $row['image_path'];

 }

    }
  ?>
```

its php script getting data from db but it not set to html tag

```html
<body>

    <table id="car-tbl">
<div id="name"><center><h3><?php echo $Name; ?></h3></center></div><br />
<tr><td>Category</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Sport Car</td></tr>
<tr><td>Transmission</td><td>&nbsp;</td> <td>Automatic</td></tr>
<tr><td>Seats</td> <td>&nbsp;</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Engine Power</td><td>&nbsp;</td> <td>420 hp</td></tr>
<tr><td>Engine Capacity</td> <td>&nbsp;</td><td>4200cc</td></tr>
<tr><td>Max Speed</td> <td>&nbsp;</td><td>301 km/h</td></tr>
<tr><td>Tank Capacity</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>75 lt</td></tr>
<tr><td>GPS</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Yes</td></tr>
</table>

</body>
```

php script is outside the body of html and I want to add these PHP data variables in html tables as you can see I have implemented some php code into the tag but it is not working , but it generating that it is undefined variable

**Help me out**

Comment: yes its correct. Any error coming or not. Try to echo "test" and check $name gives any data or not.

Comment: error is not coming when i will echo after while loop its print but when put into html tag its blank no data show

Comment: Its show in your php file not in HTML code sinppet. @Syed yasir Shah

Comment: if you need a proper output than you need explain question very well...

Comment: Please attach your whole HTML code.

Comment: Do NOT use `mysql_*` it has been removed and it will not work anymore, use `PDO` [link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or `mysqli` [link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try below code

```
  include 'connection.php';

  if(isset($_POST['val'])){
   $a = $_POST['val'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM car_details where id= '".$a."'";
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $con );
    if(! $retval ) {
      die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

     echo "<html><body><table id='car-tbl'><div id='name'><center><h3>";
     echo $Name = $row['Car_Name'];
     echo "</h3></center></div><br />";
     echo "<tr><td>Category</td><td>&nbsp;</td>";
     echo $Category = $row['Category'];
     echo "</tr>";
     echo "</table></body></html>";

    }

 }
```

Comment: How it works php code into php. Please explain. <?php two times. How it will print <h3> without echo in php tag. Its wrong. Have you tried? Please attach output.

Comment: now error is coming undefine variable <h3><?php echo $Name; ?></h3>

Comment: @RuchishParikh this is pretty clear. Try the code and you will know. Any tag outside <?php ?> will be rendered as html on client side.

Comment: h3 tag is outside the php code h3 is define into html table

Comment: Thanks dear...i understand that he need to use in html

Comment: my h3 tag inside html like <body><?php echo $Name; ?></body>

Comment: php is outside the body

Comment: is this possible that i call php into tag like <h3><?php echo $Name; ?></h3> bcoz i get data onclick and send it tbl please help , i'm trying from yestrday but its not resolve